# QTableWidget truncate beginning of long cell instead of end

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a GUI in pyqt and I use QTableWidget  to show some list of files.

When the string in a cell is too long, the end is truncated and replaced by "...".
Like in this photo
[image]

Is it possible to hide the beginning instead? something like
.../pana/someverylongblablabla.ext

Thanks

Comment: [`QAbstractItemView.setTextElideMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#textElideMode-prop): `table.setTextElideMode(Qt.ElideLeft)`

Comment: thanks, I did not know the English term "elide" which is why I wasn't able to look it up properly!

Comment: Actually, "elision" comes from Latin: a high amount of English words come from it or from Latin-origined languages (mostly French). In any case, and for future reference, it's good habit to *patiently* study the documentation. In the case of Qt, and all similarly well-written documentation, always do your research by *carefully* reading the documentation of the classes you're using and **all** the classes they also inherit from.